# adding padding between labels and indicator, react-native-step-indicator

Tags: react-native

Using this [package](https://github.com/24ark/react-native-step-indicator) and it works fine, all I need put some padding between steps and labels..

it looks pic as below,

[image]

How to add paddingTop on labels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement your own `<CustomLabel>` component and give it to the `<StepIndicator>` component via the `renderLabel` property:

```
<StepIndicator
     customStyles={customStyles}
     currentPosition={this.state.currentPosition}
     labels={labels}
     renderLabel={<CustomLabel ... style={{paddingTop: x}}>} //x is your padding above the lable
/>
```

The `<CustomLabel>` component could just be a `<Text>` component using the props that are given from the `<StepIndicator>` component.